# Display view below RecyclerView (without overlaping)

Tags: android

There are a lot of solutions where the last view is bottom aligned, but I need it to be flexible. Imagine a dialog with a list and positive/negative buttons below. If there are only few elements I'd like it to look like this:[image]

And when there are a lot of items this dialog should expand itself to the bottom, like so:

[image]

Layout structure inside `LinearLayout` is:

```
title layout
RecyclerView
buttons layout
```

I tried to wrap `RecyclerView` inside `LinearLayout` without succes it just overlap my buttons

Comment: Use a Relative layout with button layout allign to bottom . And recycler view above the buttons and below title with match parent height.

Comment: @ADM If I'll have couple items in RecyclerView then it will be a lot of empty space, using your solution

Comment: Yeah .. that's right . Well you should use alert dialog in that case ..

Comment: @VasileDoe Do you want to scroll that bottom view with recycler view's item?

Answer (score 2):

The best method is to use the NestedScrollView. Use like this :

```
<NestedScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
   <YourTitleLayout>
   <RecyclerView>
   <YourLayoutBelowRecyclerView>
 </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

This nested scrollView ensures that the the items are scrolled one after other as the name suggests. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here all 3 views will be scrollable, but we need scroll only for recyclerview

Comment: Then define the height of the recyclerView in xml. It won't exceed that height and will be scrollable in that particular area.

Comment: the height should be dynamic, what's the reason from recycle view if we set hardcoded height ?

Comment: You are missing the case where the recyclerView will have enough items to cover the entire screen.

Comment: Nope, I want it to look good for fiew items and for full list too, that's why I posted this question. I need such a layout where ReciclerView doesn't overlap buttons if list is full, and wrap content (height) if few items in list.

Comment: I would then suggest a simple solution which might work.. use a threshold value on number of items like say 5 and if items are 5 then you programatically shift height as wrap content and if greater than 5 then you put a static height let us say 7* height of each item.

Comment: This was my first idea about a quick solution, but it's not a nice one ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/splash"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_listing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_add_card"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_line"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/card_listing"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_listing"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/internet_toast"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pay_now"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with layout_weight attribute of the recyclerview. And provide fix height to the title and button below. Layout_weight makes sure recyclerview doesn't overshadows view below it.